# Bulk Transfer of Videos to Online Source

Tags: macos, iphone, iphoto

I have a lot of videos that I have recorded on my iPhone 3gs. They are now in my iPhoto Library. In a year or so if I continue I can see myself running out of space. I am looking for a method (dirty[scripts and terminal] or clean[application]) that I can send this to some online source to store.

The source/site needs to be reliable (**I would cry if they lose my videos**)

Maybe also some way like Dropbox syncing (although I started this and the upload process was slow).

What would be your recommendation to this ?

(It would be an extra plus if I can retain location and date information)

<sub>(Extra/extra plus for no loss in quality, I *heard* reuploading and downloading the same video from youtube demonstrates the loss in quality)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube upload/download will only lower quality significantly if you're recording at a higher quality than their best, which these days is HD.

However, I personally back up my videos to an external hard drive.  You can get a terabyte (1000 gig) for under $100 these days.  Since you use a Mac, be sure to get FireWire, which will give you better speed than USB 2.

Comment: +1 - Also, you could get NAS if you have a home network with more than one machine.  I've been doing the manual backup to an external for family videos but am going to get NAS and have a copy on all my machines just in case!

Comment: @JNK what is a NAS ?

Comment: @phwd - Network Attached Storage - basically a hard drive you can plug into a router and use as a shared resource on a home network.  You can get nice TB ones for around $150 now.  They are nice if you want to share videos, or music libraries, or whatever across multiple PCs in a home network.